# Cucumber.js execute same scenario multiple times

Tags: node.js, cucumber

I have created following feature:

```
 Feature:  Performing a test

  Scenario: Do test
    Given Situation X
    When  Y occures
    Then  Z should be checked
```

It is stored as single test in a feature file.

Now I want to be able to execute the scenario multiple times

1. based on a parameter indicating how many times the scenario needs to be executed.
2. based on timing, how long the scenario should be repeating itself.

Answer (score 0):

Well as no one has answered you in 6 years, let me attempt!.

This looks like tabled data.

```
Scenario: Do test
    Given Situation "<X>"
    When  "<Y>" occures
    Then  "<Z>" should be checked
  
Example:
| X    | Y  | Z   |

| a1   | a2 | a3  |
| b1   | b2 | b3  |
| c1   | c2 | c3  |
```

will be expanded into 3 tests of

```
Scenario: Do test
    Given Situation "a1"
    When  "a2" occures
    Then  "a3" should be checked

Scenario: Do test
    Given Situation "b1"
    When  "b2" occures
    Then  "b3" should be checked

Scenario: Do test
    Given Situation "c1"
    When  "c2" occures
    Then  "c3" should be checked
```

This will let you execute the given test multiple times. However its not possible to delay execution or repeat its execution on a given interval without external help (from cucumber).

You could at best make a test take longer, with a tabled data for delaying its execution a certain amount. However I suspect you may have issues with timeout's when you try to exceed certain thresholds used by what ever framework you are using.